# How to prevent Python Requests from switching to multipart transfer when I upload a large file?

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests, python-3.5, http-put

I need to upload a large file on a remote server using Python Requests. Apparently, Requests automatically switch the content type to 'multipart/form-data' when we use the `files` parameter:

```
import io
import requests
from pprint import pprint

r =requests.put('https://httpbin.org/anything/{anything}', 
                files={ 'filename': io.BytesIO(b'many many bytes')})
pprint(r.json())
```

> ```
> {'args': {},
>  'data': '',
>  'files': {'filename': 'many many bytes'},
>  'form': {},
>  'headers': {'Accept': '*/*',
>              'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
>              'Content-Length': '163',
>              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; '
>                              'boundary=f75a6ed22a9281aab1e6c7288ff34583',
>              'Host': 'httpbin.org',
>              'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.23.0',
>              'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5e8de885-83470619f8a4a57e3351b868'},
>  'json': None,
>  'method': 'PUT',
>  'origin': '80.67.177.9',
>  'url': 'https://httpbin.org/anything/{anything}'}
> ```

Unfortunately, my server does not understand that. Is there a way to disable that feature to revert to a plain HTTP upload?

FWIW, the file is way too large to fit in the main memory.

Comment: the issue is not from your code actually. it's all about `httpbin.org` server side. even for small file. the server will response back with `multipart/form-data, check [that](https://medium.com/@vdespa/automatically-testing-file-uploads-multipart-form-data-with-postman-and-gitlab-ci-ebfa371992b1)

Comment: No, @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη. I also sniffed the network, no doubt Python Requests is sending the data as `multipart/form-data`. In addition, if I upload a small file using `data=` instead of `file=`, httpbin confirms it's a plain HTTP upload.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη While posting the above comment, I suddenly thought: _"what would happen if I pass a file as the `data` parameter?"_ And guess what... ;)

Comment: LoL, was about to share that just now.

Answer (score 0):

Python Requests support [streaming upload](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads). All you have to do is to pass a file-like object in the `data=` parameter, and not in the `files=` parameter as it was shown in the question:

```
import io
import requests
from pprint import pprint

r =requests.put('https://httpbin.org/anything/{anything}',
                data=io.BytesIO(b'many many bytes'))
pprint(r.json())
```

> ```
> {'args': {},
>  'data': 'many many bytes',
>  'files': {},
>  'form': {},
>  'headers': {'Accept': '*/*',
>              'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
>              'Content-Length': '15',
>              'Host': 'httpbin.org',
>              'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.23.0',
>              'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5e8df4cc-fb2b5fdd121ba761f97d959a'},
>  'json': None,
>  'method': 'PUT',
>  'origin': '80.67.177.9',
>  'url': 'https://httpbin.org/anything/{anything}'}
> ```